# Angular CLI Proxy with env variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, proxy

I need to create a proxy to my backend server in order to communicate with it. I've already succesfully set this up, but now I have 2 places where I need to change variables when changing the environment.

My versions:

- Angular CLI `7.0.6`
- Angular `7.1.0`

**NOTE:** I have the proxy working (see [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) for the setup), I only want to **improve** the setup.

---

**Proxy.conf.js**

This is my current (and working!) config.js

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://url.to.somewhere/",
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

What I would like it to combine this file with the Angular **environment.ts** file.

---

**What I want**

I would like to use the variables from the environment.ts file to configure the proxy, so I would only have to maintain my environment.ts instead of both files (also the **proxy.conf.js**).

*Something along the lines of this:*

```
import {env} from 'environments/environment';

const root = env.BASE_SUFFIX + '/*'; // BASE_SUFFIX = '/api'

function getConfig() {
  const PROXY_CONFIG = {};
  PROXY_CONFIG[root] = {
    target: env.API_URL, // API_URL = https://url.to.somewhere/
    logLevel: "debug",
    changeOrigin: true,
  };

  return PROXY_CONFIG;
}

module.exports = getConfig();
```

The problem I currently run into is that environment.ts is a Typescript file and cannot be correctly included by the javascript, because I have some `import {foo} from 'bar'` in my environment.ts file.

So `const env = require(environments/environment.ts).env` is not working, due to the ES6 imports.

---

Any suggestions on how I should do this or is this not possible and should I just use 2 separate files?

Comment: If you use a proxy config in proxy.conf.json, you just need to call /api and it will do http://url.to.somewhere/api

Comment: and you need to add your proxy conf file in your start command 
for my project I did it like this :     "start": "node node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --proxy-config proxy.conf.json" in package.json

Comment: @Alann, I have a working setup, so that is not the problem. 
The problem is that I do NOT want to hardcode variables in the file, because then I would have to change the code in 2 places. I want to use the Angular environment.ts variables in the js file (cannot use .json, because it doesn't support variables)

Comment: @Alann the setup you are suggesting in your `package.json` (`start`) is not the way Angular or the Angular-CLI is suggesting how you should do it btw. See my post for the link to the Angular page on how you should set it up.

Comment: hey chek this url i am using this solution for now to get env variables dynamically https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318#issuecomment-293829342

Comment: Why would you need to change "it" in two places? With the proxy in place all your http requests should use relative URLs, like `/api/path/to/endpoint`. If anything you should delete the URL from the `environment.ts` file.

Comment: @jrasm91 is right. I dont see any relation between proxy.config and environment file.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm using it this way. you can try this**

// create proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

// in package.json file "scripts" under that find "start"

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

// api call

```
this.http.post('/api/api_name/')
```